# How to convert Unicode (or what ever that is) to UTF-8 (or or what ever is readable) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used code from a YouTube video :

```
import json
import re
import requests

class Helper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def id_from_url(self, url: str):
        return url.rsplit("/", 1)[1]

class YouTubeStats:
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        #self.json_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        self.json_url = requests.get(url)
        self.data = json.loads(self.json_url.text)
        
    def print_data(self):
        print(self.data)

    def get_video_title(self):
        return self.data["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]

    def get_video_description(self):
        return self.data["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]


api_key = "never-gonna-let-you-know"

link_file = "links.csv"

with open(link_file, "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), content))
content = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(','), content))

helper = Helper()
for youtube_url in content:
    video_id = helper.id_from_url(youtube_url)
    url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={video_id}&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={api_key}"
    yt_stats = YouTubeStats(url)
    title = yt_stats.get_video_title()
    description = yt_stats.get_video_description()

    print(title)
```

and when ever i use it keeps on showing funky characters (`&#39;`) instead of an apostrophe.

Note : this might get updated and fix itself since its a API but please use ^ as a reference also my API key might break

Comment: oh and yeah im gonna remove the description parameter

Comment: Did you *really* just post your API key on the net where *everyone* can see it? Is that supposed to be a private thing?

Comment: FWIW, it’s an *HTML entity*.

Comment: @paxdiablo its a youtube API key its not important to me

Answer (score 0):

Well NVM i figured it out i just needed to use : `html.unescape()` to convert